# How to collapse dataframe by grouping and concatenating on one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 20 columns. The last column is a text field. I'd like to group by the first 19 columns, and concatenate the values for the last text column. 
I have been trying to achieve this by using dplyr as follows:

```
mydf %>%
group_by(col1, col2, col3, ... col19) %>%
summarise(alltasks = c(col20))
```

But this does not work and returns with this error message:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : expecting a single
>   value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `c` will just return all the values in each group, which isn't a single summary value like `summarise` requires. Without knowing what it is you want exactly, maybe `summarise(alltasks=toString(col20))`

Comment: Try `paste` or `toString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out, you need to return a single value, rather than a vector of all of the values. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
dots = lapply(paste0("col", 1:19), as.symbol)

mydf %>%
  group_by_(.dots=dots) %>%
  summarise(alltasks = paste(col20, collapse=", "))
```

The change to the `summarise` line is how you paste together all the values from `col20` into a single string. I used a comma-space separator, but you can of course change that to whatever you prefer. The `dots` business is just an easier way to combine all the grouping variables without typing out each one.

If the names of `mydf` aren't so regular that you can use a simple `paste` function to generate them, other options would be, for example:

```
dots = lapply(names(mydf)[1:19], as.symbol)
```

or

```
dots = lapply(names(mydf)[-grep("col20$", names(mydf))], as.symbol)
```

Here's a working example of the `dplyr` code using the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
dots = lapply(c("am","vs","cyl","carb"), as.symbol)

mtcars %>%
  group_by_(.dots=dots) %>%
  summarise(all_mpg = paste(mpg, collapse=", "))
```

> ```
>       am    vs   cyl  carb                      all_mpg
> 1      0     0     8     2       18.7, 15.5, 15.2, 19.2
> 2      0     0     8     3             16.4, 17.3, 15.2
> 3      0     0     8     4 14.3, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 13.3
> 4      0     1     4     1                         21.5
> 5      0     1     4     2                   24.4, 22.8
> 6      0     1     6     1                   21.4, 18.1
> 7      0     1     6     4                   19.2, 17.8
> 8      1     0     4     2                           26
> 9      1     0     6     4                       21, 21
> 10     1     0     6     6                         19.7
> 11     1     0     8     4                         15.8
> 12     1     0     8     8                           15
> 13     1     1     4     1       22.8, 32.4, 33.9, 27.3
> 14     1     1     4     2             30.4, 30.4, 21.4
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful and exactly what I was looking for,